# Why do I get an error with my usage of C++ friend functions?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn friend function in C++, despite defining display() as a friend function, it's unable to access variable a and b. That's why compiler is showing error.

[image: original code]

Comment: You need to pass an `Add` object to `display()`. Also, in the future, please do not post images of code. Post the actual code. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Post the code and the output as text. You can provide a link to C++ shell as extra.

Comment: `display() {cout << a << b;}` : `a` and `b` of which *instance* of `class Add`? You can have any number of those: `Add add1, add2;`

Answer (score 2):

Who is `display` supposed to display? Being friend just means that if you run across an object of that class you can access all its innards. You probably want:

```
void display(const Add &a) {
    cout << a.a + a.b;
}
```

And then you can call it in `main` with:

```
display(A);
```

(remember you'll need to change the definition of `display` in the class too!)

Answer (score 1):

For better explanation friend function is for accessing private or protected attributes of the class from outside (that it shouldn't reach without proper accessors). A better explaining answer can be found at

[Example taken from programiz:](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/friend-function-class)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// forward declaration
class B;
class A {
    private:
      int numA;
    public:
      A(): numA(12) { }
      // friend function declaration
      friend int add(A, B);
};

class B {
    private:
       int numB;
    public:
       B(): numB(1) { }
       // friend function declaration
       friend int add(A , B);
};

// Function add() is the friend function of classes A and B
// that accesses the member variables numA and numB
int add(A objectA, B objectB)
{
   return (objectA.numA + objectB.numB);
}

int main()
{
    A objectA;
    B objectB;
    cout<<"Sum: "<< add(objectA, objectB);
    return 0;
}
```

on normal cases that add function out of the classes shouldn't reach numA or numB attributes since they are private but since it is declared as friend it gives no error. So on your problem you should do it like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    class Add {
        private:
            int a, b; 
            /*Declared as private to show the significance of friend otherwise
             *it does not make sense*/
        public:
            void get_data();
            friend void display(Add);
    }

    //And change the display function
    void display(Add obj) {
        cout << (obj.a + obj.b);
    }
```